# toilet troubles

Tags: plumbing, old-house

I have a brass tube for water coming into a toilet in my very old farmhouse.  The shut off valve failed and I had to cut the tube and am now trying to fix it... to no avail.  We are three days without water in the house and the kids and I are going stir crazy without showers.  I can't seem to find a 5/8 OD 1/2 ID fitting, shark bites don't work and regular compression fittings don't either, as they are all made for copper pipe these days.  Can someone help me find an unthreaded, weldable cap for this stupid thing? I have three or four months til the new house is done, I just have to make it til then... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this water line feeds into a toilet there is less concern about the type of repair used as a temporary fix for this situation. You should consider getting a suitably sized rubber pressure hose that can slide over the brass tubing and secure it in place using one or two gear type hose clamps.

On the other end you can adapt the hose to replacement valve as needed even if such valve is left somewhat free handing for the few months it is needed.

Comment: I may have to try this. I have amazingly strong water pressure, though...  I did call in a friend who used to do contract plumbing and now does commercial hvac... we'll see what he thinks.  Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

This fitting here:
[https://www.amazon.com/Generic-Brass-Compression-Connector-Fitting/dp/B00CHHZTGY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CHHZTGY)

It comes in a size for 5/8" O.D. with 1/2" NPT threads so you can put a standard 1/2" pipe cap on it. Make sure you clean the brass pipe first so their is no leftover paint or dirt. Use teflon tape to seal the threads on the NPT side.

You should be able to find this fitting at a big box store but if not, have Amazon overnight you one.

Good luck!

Comment: I like @Michael Karas's idea also. I guess I was thinking you were just trying to cap off this pipe but if not, you could adapt the 1/2" NPT side to feed the toilet.

Comment: It was recommended to me to just cap the pipe and stop using that toilet unless I wanted to bring in water jugs to flush it.  I definitely need a non-threaded cap for this, but thank you for the advice.  I'll search amazon more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the 5/8OD is the exact size of the tube you are working with, then that is the size of standard copper tubing used today. They do sell compression fittings that size. If this tubing is not that exact size you may have tubing 1/2" OD or 3/4 "OD. Copper water tubing comes in  sizes 1/2", 3/4" and 1" ID, while refrigeration tubing comes in sizes 1/2", 5/8", 3/4", 7/8",OD.

Comment: I have tried every fitting in the plumbing section, maybe I will try another section.  I'm just positive this tube coming up out of the floor is brass - it's very thick-walled stuff, and does not bend or crimp. thanks for the advice.

Comment: Is the pipe threaded into the fitting or valve beneath it or is it soldered? Can you post a picture of it and what it connects to. There has to be a fitting that fits it.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10211563593799010&set=pcb.10211563594079017&type=3

Comment: Still waiting for photo of pipe,etc.

Comment: sorry, i couldn't upload photos, wasn't in the mood to figure that out in addition to everything else.  Finally took up part of the floor in desperation, that solved the problem.  Took out the brass tube and replaced it with copper, everythings good now.  Thanks for all the help